# Errno 18: Invalid cross-device link

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am writing a function on amazon lambda and wrote the script below, but I'm getting an error. The script runs whenever an object is put into an S3 Bucket.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    path = '/tmp/videos'
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key'] 
        try:
            response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
            print("CONTENT TYPE: " + response['ContentType'])
            video_path = '/tmp/{}'.format(key)
            download_path = '/tmp/'
            print('video path: ' + video_path)
            print('download path: ' + download_path)
            print('key: ' + key)
            print('bucket: ' + bucket)
            s3.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
            raise e
```

I tested the function and got the following output:

```
START RequestId: aa42300f-5f52-11e6-a14e-a3511b08d368 Version: $LATEST
CONTENT TYPE: video/mp4
video path: /tmp/videos/20160810-182413-jjrni-capturedvideo.mp4
download path: /tmp/
key: videos/20160810-182413-jjrni-capturedvideo.mp4
bucket: bucket
[Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link
Error getting object videos/20160810-182413-jjrni-capturedvideo.mp4 from bucket bucket. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.
[Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link: OSError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/CreateThumbnail.py", line 48, in lambda_handler
    raise e
OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link
END RequestId: aa42300f-5f52-11e6-a14e-a3511b08d368
```

The error is coming from:

```
s3.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
```

I'm not sure why there is an error downloading the file when s3 can retrieve the key and bucket from:

```
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
```

Any help is appreciated!
(The S3 bucket is in US Standard, which I think is US-East1, and the Lambda function is in US-N. Virginia)

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks similar to this one https://github.com/amorton/cassback/issues/2

How about building relative path  instead of file from /tmp?

Also why do you need getting the file in server?

Comment: I need to run a script every time a video is uploaded to the S3 bucket. I followed the code from this tutorial in the python section: [aws lambda python example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html) and they used the path of the file from /tmp